# Adding entry's to YOURLS .htaccess causes 500 internal server error

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yourls

I have a website, tini.link. It is powered by a heavily modified version of `YOURLS`. Everything is working fine, people can go and create short link and so on. I want to speed the site up, but every time I try to add anything to `.htaccess`, I just get a 500 internal server error when visiting my site. This is what my `.htaccess` looks like at the moment:

```
IfModule mod_rewrite.c <br>
RewriteEngine On <br>
RewriteBase / <br>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f <br>
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d <br>
 RewriteRule ^.*$ /yourls-loader.php [L] <br>
 IfModule <br>
```

Thanks,
Flynn

Comment: what are you tring to add ?

Comment: You don't have `<br>` in real file right?

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess looks fine
try to change your php version to newest one